# How do I use a procedure to run a select that exports to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

How do I use a procedure to run a select that exports to an excel spreadsheet? 
Using PL/SQL - Oracle 11g

We currently have people copy pasting information into spread sheets that they use for testing every release. I am trying to convert all of their statements into one procedure that will run it for them instead of wasting days worth of time pasting.

Comment: Does it need to write the data to an actual .xlsx / .xls file or would it suffice to write the data to a .csv file that can be opened in Excel? The reason that I ask is that it is considerably easier to do the latter. There is no built in functionality to write directly to Excel that I know of, though I have heard of libraries written by third parties to do this.

Comment: Could you create a view in a separate reporting Schema that your users could connect to through Excel using an ODBC Connection?

Comment: YEs a .csv file would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following simple query you could have your whole set of tables converted in XML, one clob row for each table:

```
SELECT DBMS_XMLQUERY.getxml('select * from ' || table_name)
FROM user_tables;
```

The package [DBMS_XMLQUERY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10802/d_xmlque.htm) has many option to control the format, but you could just write down XML on files (with a custom client, or directly by PLS [UTL_FILE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm)), spreadsheets area able to import them.

Comment: What I need pulled is from many tables to make one result set. Would I still be able to use this kind of statement somehow?

Comment: Yes, you could simply make a UNION: the query withing GETXML function is generic.

Example that return the union of names of all tables and views in current schema:

SELECT DBMS_XMLQUERY.getxml('select table_name from user_tables UNION select view_name from user_views') FROM DUAL